# Website not displaying a page on IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

In IE 8 and below and other browsers, the website appears correctly.

But in IE 9, only the header and footer are displayed the rest of the content is not. And its just for a single page, the rest are fine.

I checked the view source, and the content is available there, just not being displayed.

I tried the Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering, but it doesn't make any difference.

Please help.

Webpage in question: http://www.jabrdeals.com/?fuseaction=business.groupbuy.publicpage.recent

Comment: More details such as code and the specific area that is failing would be helpful.

Comment: The htmlis incorrectly formatted. e.g. you have `<div>` tags within your `<head>` section. might not be the cause of the problem as there seems to be something crazy going on, but good to make sure you have valid html

Comment: You page is way way too long.  It took nearly forever to load.  Have you tested it in IE 9 with only a portion of all that content?

Comment: [Sixteen Hundred Validation errors...](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jabrdeals.com%2F%3Ffuseaction%3Dbusiness.groupbuy.publicpage.recent&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: "Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!
Result:  1600 Errors, 651 warning(s)" http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.jabrdeals.com/?fuseaction=business.groupbuy.publicpage.recent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are duplicating a few `id`'s hundreds of times.  `id`'s must be unique per element or browsers can simply ignore subsequent instances.

```
<div id="recentdealimg">

<div id="recentdealholder" align="left">

<div id="recentdeal">
```

You need to closely examine all [1600 HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.jabrdeals.com/?fuseaction=business.groupbuy.publicpage.recent&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) found on that page.

"HTML Validation" means that your code meets a set of "W3C standards" for your particular `doctype`.  "Standards" are the rules browsers strive to follow.  A perfectly compliant browser will follow the standards perfectly, and non-compliant code will likely fail in that *perfect* browser.

Most browsers are not perfect, so when you feed it non-compliant code, you're likely to get unpredictable results... i.e., maybe it works and maybe it won't or it works in one browser but not another.

Comment: Does this affect rendering of a page? I thought it would only affect scripts. Asking because its old code. Didn't want to change it unnecessarily.

Comment: @CharlieBrown, those are **HTML** validation errors, nothing to do with JavaScript. So yes, HTML compliance has everything to do with how HTML is rendered.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sparky672, this was very helpful. I never knew that these HTML validation errors affected rendering. But how come it happens only in IE9 and not in any other browser?

Comment: @CharlieBrown, It has to do with the fact that every browser is going to follow compliance standards differently.  IE 9 is more compliant than IE 8, 7, etc.  Maybe it's easier to choke IE 9 with compliance errors than Firefox or Safari, etc.  Every browser is going to try to correct for minor errors, close open tags, ignore misplaced tags, etc. so apparently IE 9 just could not handle the "auto-correction" of your particular errors.